# Cannot execute dpkg command in kube-proxy container

Tags: debian, docker, kubernetes, containers, dpkg

I'm currently trying to get a list of all installed debian packages (dpkg) on the `k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.23.2` container.

First I tried to execute `dpkg -l` in the running container as a part of my kubernetes cluster but got the following error.

```
dpkg-query: error: showing package list on pager subprocess returned error exit status 127
```

Then I also tried the command directly on containerd `nerdctl run -it k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.23.2 dpkg -l` but got the same error.

Is it possible to get the list by modifying some settings, or is there any different approach?

Comment: Hi, Daigo did the answer below solve your issue?

Comment: Yeah, it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that `dpkg` attempts to run a pager (`less`) but it is not found in `PATH` so your get `127` exist code. Run `dpkg -l --no-pager`.